# PHP Session variable is not saving

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I've looked through all the problems about the session variable not saving and don't see my problem so I'm going to ask it.

I have a form that once submitted it searches my database for that name. The initial form is on page 1.
On page 2 I take the the variable from page 1 and save it like this

```
    $searchTerm = $_POST['find'];
```

which is used as the search for the database and it works perfectly. Under that I have my sql statement then I have placed this

```
    //initialize the session
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['searchTerm'] = $searchTerm;
```

I have then tested the $_SESSION['searchTerm'] on page 2 to make sure that it is saving properly, and it does. My issue comes in when I try to go to a 3rd page that is a confirm page for the form from page 2. I have the session start clause at the top of the 3rd page and I even inserted

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to check for errors, no errors were displayed. So my next step was to test the session itself to see if it was refreshing the session id. I found a script on this site www.webassist.com/forums/posts.php?id=5735 to test whether the server could possibly be causing the issue. The script works fine no problems, showing that the server is not the problem. However when I upload my 2nd and 3rd page to the server and put in

```
    <?php echo session_id(); ?>
```

the numbers from page 2 and page 3 are completely different therefore making my variable null. I did further research and thought it might be because there was a session_destroy or session_unset but I didn't put one of these on either page. When I tried this on my local machine I got the same session id but still the session variable I set was blank.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how or why this would happen?

***************edit* ***********************************

page 1 has this form

```
                <form name="search" method="post" action="page2.php">
                    <div>
                    <!-- Search-->
                    <label>Search by Last Name:</label>
                        <div>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="" name="find" placeholder=""></td>
                                    <td><button id="submit" type="submit"><span>Search</span></button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

page 2

```
    $searchTerm = $_POST['find'];


    if(!empty($searchTerm ) && ctype_alpha($searchTerm ))
    {
    $whereclause = "WHERE mytable.lastName = '".$searchTerm ."'";
    }
    else {
    $whereclause = "";
    }

    // sql query is here this one searches it is long and just used the $whereclause above.

    // second sql query that is only submitted if button from the form below is hit is here.

    $insertGoTo = "confirmPage3.php";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ;

      }
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));

    //initialize the session
    if (session_id() == '') {
      session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['searchTerm'] = $searchTerm;


    // then the form is listed below that with the rest of the html
```

page 3

```
    <?php if(session_id() == '') session_start(); ?> 

    if(!empty($_SESSION['searchTerm']) && ctype_alpha($_SESSION['searchTerm']))
    {
    $whereclause = "WHERE myTable.lastName = '".$_SESSION['searchTerm'] ."'";
    }
    else {
    $whereclause = "";
    }

    // More sql statement here for this one it is only selecting not updating or changing anything.

    // Table below this that is used to hold the items retrieved from the database.
```

******************edit 2 and my fix***********************

so after some back and for with a few of you, Aaron Gong suggested I start with a blank page and go from there. I did this and have finally diagnosed the issue. It was something that I hadn't thought of that I very well should have. I don't like using dreamweaver and now I remember why. When I originally created the page 2 I used dreamweavers insert code to insert my sql statement to do the updating. Well it placed in the code these lines of code.

```
    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }
```

This will completely mess with you if you are trying to send the user to another page to confirm their entries. I commented it out and set the $editFormAction to my page and used that in the header string and viola that immediately fixed my issue. What I hadn't realized is when it was refreshing the page that it was emptying my $_POST variable and found that error finally through the empty pages suggest by Aaron.

Hope this helps someone else and I will never trust the code from dreamweaver again. I learned to code by hand and should know better but I was in a hurry and thought oh it won't harm it.

Thanks again to all your suggestions.

Comment: Are you starting the session on every page that you want to use the `$_SESSION` variable or create it?

Comment: yes the $_SESSION variable and the session start are on all pages that the need to be on.

Comment: Why do you think any code will execute after you changed the `header` location? Please try my answer. Also, remove the `if` statement from page 3. Just do `session_start()`. No ifs, ands, or buts.

Comment: Check out the PHP page on `session_start()` if you don't believe me! :). Scroll down to the Examples. Do you see them checking for an existing session? No, they just call `session_start()` and go from there. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#example-4724

Comment: I only put the check in to see if that was the problem either way it still fails.

Comment: It is not the problem. You should put it back to normal and keep looking elsewhere. There seems to be no reason for page 2 to even exist. Why not put that query-creating code right into page 3? Also, you said you are using `display errors`. Is it displaying any errors ever? Make sure your debugging tool is working before you rely on it.

Comment: page 2 exists so that the user can change stuff that was pulled from the database. page 3 exists so that the user can confirm their inputs. I did add the error reporting to the top of page 3 but unfortunately I got no errors showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your 3rd page looks like but mine would be:

```
session_start(); // Use session variable on this page. This function must put on the top of page.

if( isset($_SESSION['i_am_in']) ) echo "logged in";
```

My Page 2:

```
if ($login_ok) {
    session_start(); // Create session & settings
    $_SESSION['abc123'] = 'whatever';
    header('Location: page3.php');
}
```

Comment: 3rd page is just a confirm page it takes all input from page 2 that the user has inserted and displays it so they can confirm that is what they wanted it to say. The top of my page is something similar to what you have there, except I had If(!isset($_SESSION))...

Comment: session_start(); is at the very top of your page correct? See the examples on the php site http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php, session_start(); is always on top.

Comment: yes on page 3 it is at the top which is the page that is causing the issue.

Comment: ok, btw, if you are using session_destroy(); $_SESSION = array(); you are killing off the session, could you try commenting  those out and see?

Comment: I know I tried to see if that would fix the issue and all it does is log out a user it doesn't output the variable on page 3.

Comment: Could you try <?php session_start(); ?> instead of <?php  if(session_id() == '') session_start(); ?> for  page 3? You need the session_start first, I think u can skip the if check

Comment: I can try that again but I had it once before and the confirm page 3 was still outputting wrong data.---- Tried and still failed, on page 3 my print_r($_SESSION) says this Array ( [searchTerm] =>)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36218/discussion-between-aaron-gong-and-puddlejumper)

Comment: So finally found the bug that was causing the issue for the rest of you I have placed it in my original post.

Comment: Dreamweaver! No wonder it was so wierd, anywaym good to know that its finally cleared! Someone add Dreamweaver to the tag, can be useful in future.

Answer (score 4):

make a call to the **session_start()** function.

```
session_start()
```

This call should be in every script that needs to utilise the session data. For example, if you have a script that creates a CAPTCHA image and needs to store the secret word for the session, you will need to put session_start() at the beginning of the script. If you have another script that takes the user input for the form and checks the secret word entered by the user against what you stored earlier, you will also need to put session_start() in that script.

The function **session_start() takes no parameters**. It always returns **TRUE**, so you don't have to bother to check its return value. since session_start() sets a cookie via the HTTP cookie header, ***you must call it before you output anything from your script***. It's best to simply call it at the beginning of your script.

**Ending Sessions**

**session_destroy()** is used to destroy the data associated with a session. **However, this in itself does not clean up everything**. For example, the session cookie is not unset. The $_SESSION array is also still available until your script ends.

To remove the cookie, manually delete it using the usual method one uses to delete a cookie in PHP. To get the name of the cookie to delete, call the session_name() function, which returns a string that is also the name of the cookie set by the PHP session handler.

*example code for how you can clean up after a session can be found in the official PHP manual.

Comment: I know that the session start is supposed to be called at the top of the page. The only reason it isn't called at the top on page 2 is because it messes with the headers that are sent on a line below that.

Answer (score 3):

Page 1 is good, Page 2 and Page 3 should look something like this

**PAGE 2**

```
//initialize the session and set are $_SESSION variable from the form data
session_start();
$_SESSION['searchTerm'] = $_POST['find'];

//set where condition and check if $_POST['find'] has a value
$whereclause = "";
if(isset($_POST['find'])) {
    $whereclause = "WHERE mytable.lastName = '".$_POST['find']."'";
}

/*execute your statement note: data passed such as $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION should never 
be directly in your statement, use PDO to prepare and execute your statements to prevent 
SQL injection*/

//then if you wanted to be redirected to page 3 use header after your statement has executed

header('Location:comfirmPage3.php');
```

**PAGE 3**

```
//initialize the session so we can access our $_SESSION variables
session_start(); 

//set where condition and check is $_SESSION['searchTerm'] has a value
$whereclause = "";
if(isset($_SESSION['searchTerm'])) {
    $whereclause = "WHERE myTable.lastName = '".$_SESSION['searchTerm'] ."'";
}
//execute your statement
```

Comment: If I run the session_destroy it logs out the user. I already tried it.

Comment: Can you post the code of page 1, 2 and 3 so I can see exactly what's going on?

Comment: added those page or the relevant parts of them above.

Answer (score 2):

**replace**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
}
```

**with**

```
session_start();
```

because `$_SESSION` is super global and its always available.

**OR**

Try checking for a specific `$_SESSION` ex. `$_SESSION['session']` rather than just a `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I have even dumped the session to the page to see what it was saving and it isn't saving the variable I inserted into on page 2.

Comment: without calling `session_start`, `$_SESSION` should return null.... means you should be able to use it in a control structure.

Comment: @itachi, there's no point in using it in a control structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(session_id() == ''){
    session_start();
}
```

since $_SESSION is always available.

Comment: The session id is still the same on my local machine but the $_SESSION['searchTerm'] is still empty.

Comment: it should be the very first thing you do in your script.

Comment: I know it needs to be the first thing on the page that is unless you are sending headers which have to come before it or they throw an error.

Comment: ctype_alpha($_SESSION['searchTerm']), are you sure that your query contains only letters?

Comment: most definitely I have typed it in so many times. I even tried removing it to see if that fixed it nope, still fails.

Comment: what is the output if you use var_dump($_SESSION); rigt after your session_start();

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem since 10 minutes ago and no answer helped me. I'm giving you another possible answer (you solved your problem but other people might have not).

I had `file1.php` opening a session and saving a session variable, `file2.php` opening the session and retrieving that variable from `$_SESSION`. It didn't work and I also had two different sessions from `file1` and `file2`. The reason was that `file1.php` was saved as `UTF-8 WITH BOM` I it saved again with Notepad++ as `UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM`.

Now everything works perfectly. I'm sure many people will fall in this problem I couldn't even think of.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()`

That should be right at the top of your scripts. No `if` statements to determine whether to start it or not.

**PAGE 2**
In the second script, you have `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));` before you have `session_start()`. Your session would never start if the header location is changed.

Put `session_start()` at the top. Do not surround it with the if statement.

**PAGE 3**
Also put `session_start()` at the top of the third page, without any if statement. You are not understanding session usage. It's not like a regular function. You must start the session first on every page you want to use it. You can't check for the contents of a $_SESSION variable before you call `session_start()`.

Let me know when you've done that and what the results are.

Comment: yes I removed these and move it back to the top but I still get the same results. Aaron Gong has done some testing as well and it doesn't make sense my code should work, but for some reason the session is being destroyed on page 3 and the variable disappears.

Comment: @puddleJumper Entire session disappears or just your variable?

Comment: I'm not sure because a minute ago I would have said it was the session but now I'm not so sure. I was testing a blank page and hit the back arrow on the browser because I go a NULL for a var_dump but when I hit the forward arrow the var_dump actually output what I searched for.

Comment: I have a feeling that your page redirect is a major part of the problem. You do realize that your redirect is NOT located inside an IF statement, right? So it will always execute no matter what.

Comment: The redirect is actually inside a statement associated with the update sql statement so technically it is. and I want it to go to that page once the sql statement has been executed.

Comment: @puddleJumper What reason do you have for using a separate page for that? Does the SQL statement take a very long time to execute? Even so, I can't think of any reason that it should be on a separate page.

Comment: I created the page so it is easier to edit If I didn't then I would have 2 very large forms on one page as well as 3 separate sql statements depending upon what the user has selected. It makes the page very hard to manage with that much on a single page-

Comment: Ok so Aaron and I have narrowed it down a bit for anyone following. I can assign a session variable to a static "ABC" but the minute I try to set it to my $_POST variable it looses its mind.

Comment: @puddleJumper you can create a ftp account and give it access to those files and back it up first and I'll have a look at it if you want e-mail me the login info to mitchlayzell@gmail.com

Comment: @puddleJumper If only we knew what you were actually trying to accomplish with all this code, perhaps we could redirect you!

Comment: I have them on a server but it requires a password that is not mine to give. It is on someone else's server. I have gone to the add from page to to a blank page to find out what is causing the issue. because that is working at the moment. as long as I can keep it working I'll be good. Thanks for all your guys help. I really appreciate it. I will post what works when I get the fix I'm looking for.

Comment: I am updating an entry in the database nothing more with a confirm page that is all. Nothing fancy just a form that they fill out to update an existing entry.

Comment: You are almost certainly destroying the session, overwriting the variable, or not starting the session at the top of every page. But maybe not. Good luck.